# SDL2 | Wrapper class access violation

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I’ve been making some very simple wrappers around some of the SDL2 functionality. I created a class that wrapped `SDL_Window*` and a class that wrapped `SDL_Surface*`.

Within my `SDL_Surface` wrapper (`SDL2::Surface`), the constructor takes in the `SDL2:::Window` wrapper and associates the `SDL_Window*` (via a getter call) to the `SDL_Surface*` member variable in `SDL2::Surface`.

Then, I have `SDL2::Surface::FillRect()` which calls:

```
SDL_FillRect(Surface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(Surface->format, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF));
```

Under this construct, I get an access violation exception on the call to `SDL_FillRect`. However, if I wrap both `SDL_Window*` and `SDL_Surface` into one wrapper class, the call to `SDL_FillRect` from that class works fine.

What could possibly be the difference between these two approaches?

```
// Surface.h
namespace SDL2 {
    class Window {
        private:
            SDL_Window* mWindow;
            int ScreenWidth = 640;
            int ScreenHeight = 480;

        public:
            Window();
            ~Window();
            SDL_Window* GetWindow();

    }
}

// Surface.cpp
SDL2::Window::Window() {
    mWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Breakout", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
}

SDL2::Window::~Window() {
    SDL_DestroyWindow(mWindow);
{        

// Surface.h
namespace SDL2 {
    class Surface {
        private:
            SDL_Surface* Surface;

        public:
            Surface(SDL2::Window window);
            ~Surface();
            void FillRect();
            void Update(SDL2::Window window);
    }
}

// Wrapper.cpp
SDL2::Surface::Surface(SDL2::Window window) {
    Surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window.GetWindow());
    }

void SDL2::Surface::FillRect() {
        SDL_FillRect(Surface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(Surface->format, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF)); // Access violation when this is called
        }

void SDL2::Surface::Update(SDL2::Window window) {
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window.GetWindow());
}

// main.cpp
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Wrapper.h"
#include "Window.h"

int main() {
    //Initialize SDL
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    SDL2::Window window = SDL2::Window();

    SDL2::Surface surface = SDL2::Surface(window);

    surface.FillRect();

    SDL_Delay(2000);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you're making shallow copies without realizing it, and a temporary object is deallocating your resources. We need to see code.

Comment: You've got some [rule-of-three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) violation right there.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, thanks for pointing that out - this has been great practice for me.  As of now, I want to prevent SDL2::Surface and SDL2::Window from being copied so I added the copy constructor and copy assignment definition as private and left them undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Surface(SDL2::Window window)
                    ^ missing &
```

You're passing your `Window`s by value, causing `~Window()` to nuke the underlying `SDL_Window` as soon as the `Surface` constructor returns, invalidating the surface returned by `SDL_GetWindowSurface()`.

Pass them by reference instead:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

namespace SDL2
{
class Window
{
private:
    SDL_Window* mWindow;
    int ScreenWidth = 640;
    int ScreenHeight = 480;

public:
    Window()
    {
        mWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( "Breakout", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
    }

    ~Window()
    {
        SDL_DestroyWindow( mWindow );
    }

    SDL_Window* GetWindow()
    {
        return mWindow;
    }
};

class Surface
{
private:
    SDL_Surface* mSurface;

public:
    Surface( SDL2::Window& window )
    {
        mSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( window.GetWindow() );
    }

    void FillRect()
    {
        SDL_FillRect( mSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB( mSurface->format, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF ) );
    }

    void Update( SDL2::Window& window )
    {
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window.GetWindow() );
    }
};
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    //Initialize SDL
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        return 1;
    }

    SDL2::Window window = SDL2::Window();

    SDL2::Surface surface = SDL2::Surface( window );

    surface.FillRect();

    surface.Update( window );

    SDL_Delay( 2000 );

    return 0;
}
```